# How can I override behavior of JSONEncoder for binary data?

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm working in Python 2.7.10, and I have some binary data:

```py
binary_data = b'\x01\x03\x00\x00 \xe6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

(If you're *really* curious, that's an [Extended WKB](https://github.com/postgis/postgis/blob/2.1.0/doc/ZMSgeoms.txt) of a geometry.)

Actually, I have this data somewhere inside a `dict`:

```py
my_data = {
    'something1': 5.5,
    'something2': u'Some info',
    'something3': b'\x01\x03\x00\x00 \xe6\x10\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xf0?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00',
}
```

I want to serialize this to JSON to store it. The problem is I get an error because `json` wrongly tries to interpret it as UTF-8:

```
>>> json.dumps(my_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python\27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python\27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 5: invalid continuation byte
```

I could encode it manually:

```py
my_serializable_data = dict(my_data.items())
my_serializable_data['something3'] = binascii.b2a_base64(my_serializable_data['something3'])
json.dumps(my_serializable_data)
```

gives a nice

```
'{"something2": "Some info", "something3": "AQMAACDmEAAAAQAAAAUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAPA/AAAAAAAA8D8AAAAAAADwPwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==\\n", "something1": 5.5}'
```

But this would be cumbersome as I will need to redo this throughout my app. I'd much rather customize `json`'s behavior for this binary. Normally, you'd inform `json` how to serialize something by overriding `JSONEncoder.default` like so:

```py
class MyJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            return binascii.b2a_base64(o)

        return super(MyJsonEncoder, self).default(o)
```

But this has no effect, presumably because the handling of `str` is hard coded into `JSONEncoder`:

```
>>> json.dumps(my_data, cls=MyJsonEncoder)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\27\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python\27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Python\27\Lib\json\encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 5: invalid continuation byte
```

Overriding `JSONEncoder.encode` *should* work, but I would need to reconstruct a significant amount of logic from the built in library since that method knows how to dig down into arbitrary levels and combinations of `list`s and `dict`s. I'd prefer not to do that; it would get ugly fast and is error prone. (Additionally, looking at the source code, it looks like that logic might be in *global* methods of a module in `json`, which makes this idea even messier.)

An important note here is that *deserializing* it for later consumption is not an issue for this situation. This is for logging purposes; when this data gets deserialized, it will be for viewing by a developer. If they really need to do something with the data, they can decode it manually just fine. I'm also willing to make the trade off that if some text comes through as a `str` and not a `unicode` it gets base64 encoded anyway. (Alternatively, I might revise my code to only base64 encode it if it contains any characters outside of printable ASCII, but I can't even make that decision until I can solve the problem I'm asking about here.)

So how can I override this behavior without trying to rebuild too much of `JSONEncoding`?

Comment: A solution worth noting is upgrading to Python 3, where the `bytes` type is simply interpreted as unserializable and so `default` gets called. (So you can just put some handling to call `str(binascii.b2a_base64(o), 'utf8')` for the `bytes` type in your `default` method.) Alas, I'm not at liberty to do so right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't *really* need to reconstruct everything per se.  A cheap way out is to do what you suggested and override `encode`, but construct a new `dict` with the cleaned up data.

However, if you desire the flexibility for arbitrary input for handling binary data without having to reimplement everything you could opt to monkey patch a couple functions in the `json.encoder` module. A controlled way to do so is to use a specific encoder to ensure default behavior is otherwise untouched.

```
import json
import json.encoder
import binascii

_default_encode_basestring = json.encoder.encode_basestring
_default_encode_basestring_ascii = json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii

def _check_string(s):
    if isinstance(s, str):
        try:
            s.decode('utf8')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            return False
    return True

def _encode_basestring(s):
    if not _check_string(s):
        s = binascii.b2a_base64(s)
    return _default_encode_basestring(s)

def _encode_basestring_ascii(s):
    if not _check_string(s):
        s = binascii.b2a_base64(s)
    return _default_encode_basestring_ascii(s)


class MyJsonEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):

    def encode(self, o):
        json.encoder.encode_basestring = _encode_basestring
        json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = _encode_basestring_ascii
        result = super(MyJsonEncoder, self).encode(o)
        json.encoder.encode_basestring = _default_encode_basestring
        json.encoder.encode_basestring_ascii = _default_encode_basestring_ascii     
        return result
```

A complimentary example run:

```
>>> my_data = {
...     'something1': 5.5,
...     'something2': u'Some info',
...     'something3': b'\x01\x03\x00\x00 ...\x00\x00',
... }
>>> import json
>>> r = json.dumps(my_data, cls=MyJsonEncoder)
>>> print r
{"something2": "Some info", "something3": "AQMAACDm...AAAA==\n", "something1": 5.5}
>>> r = json.dumps(my_data)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 243, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 5: invalid continuation byte
```

A nested test.

```
>>> json.dumps({'some': {'nested': {'data': [b'\xe0\x01\x02\x03?']}}}, cls=MyJsonEncoder)
'{"some": {"nested": {"data": ["4AECAz8=\\n"]}}}'
```

Comment: I apologize. I guess I wasn't clear enough. When I mentioned that the built in encode "method knows how to dig down into `list`s and `dict`s," I was referring to its ability to handle arbitrary levels of nesting. This is something I consider valuable and a behavior I would like to preserve/leverage. I'm editing that detail into the question. Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: @jpmc26 Monkey patching is unfortunately required for python2.7.  Answer updated to do what you needed.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess there's not a better way of handling this in Python 2. I ended up copy/pasting large swaths of the built in `JSONEncoder` instead of monkey patching directly (I was worried about multithreading and if someone else wrote code expecting the normal behavior.), but this showed me what I needed to modify, which wasn't too much.