# Python JSON: cutomized handling of tuples for JSON serialization

Tags: json, serialization, python-3.8

- By default, python JSONEncoder converts tuples to lists before serializing them.
- Does anyone know of a way to do custom handling of tuples using the hooks provided by the python json library?
- For example I would like to subclass the JSONEncoder class and override the handling of tuples with one of the methods in there. E.g

  ```
  class MyEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
      def default(self, obj):
          if isinstance(obj, tuple):
              print("found tuple")
              return my_tuple_handling_logic(obj)
          return JSONEncoder.default(o)

  json.dumps(my_dict, cls=MyEncoder)
  ```
- If the above worked, it would be great. But unfortunately MyEncoder.default only gets called for objects that python.json doesn't know how to serialize. And it does know how to serialize tuples. Just not in the way that I would like....
- From reading the JSONEncoder code I'm fairly sure fixing this isn't possible, but I thought I'd just ask here anyways
- To be clear - I don't want to add my own custom code which iterates through my dictionary and handles my tuples for me. I want to use the hooks provided by the python.json library

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31869554/how-can-i-override-behavior-of-jsonencoder-for-binary-data

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are correct; the code that treats tuples and lists the same:

(C implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Modules/_json.c#L1395)
(Python implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/json/encoder.py#L429)

Is executed before the default function is called:
(C implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Modules/_json.c#L1428)
(Python implementation: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/json/encoder.py#L439)

So there is no way to do this using default().

It *might* be possible, if you use the (slower) python-only implementation, to monkey around in the internals and do it, but that seems complicated and risky. Might as well

As far as I am aware, there is also no hook that can override this behavior without overriding the encode() method, which as you state, would have to iterate through the object. I don't see any way to take advantage of the existing iteration and do this.